# UK scifi book with children kidnapped in spaceship

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, childrens-novel

I read a library book in the late 60s. Set in the UK, a man takes five children for a ride in a spaceship, intending to "save them" from pending destruction of Earth.

Nerdy Brillo is able to take the controls after the man dies of radiation poisoning. Tony and Di don't want to land on the boring Moon, so they knock Brillo out and tie him up.

The little kids release Brillo, and he's able to take control back from Tony, who's not a smart as he thinks he is.

The children are all returned home safely.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Is the "pending destruction of Earth" a false alarm, or do they go home to die with everyone else?

Answer (score 14):

This is a '[Space Hostages](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Space_Hostages.html?id=oVmoDwAAQBAJ)' by Nicholas Fisk, published in 1967.

The ship was designed as the ultimate nuclear bunker for the government, but is hijacked by the lieutenant. He offers the children a tour of the ship, but takes off with them on board.

Due to overrunning the nuclear engines previously, he is dying of radiation poisoning, so the children have to learn to operate the ship.

Tony is the local bully who appoints himself 'Captain', but learns from the experience and is calmer and friendly at the end.

They weren't heading specifically for the moon, but otherwise your recollection matches.

Comment: This rings a faint bell. Is there a scene where Tony gains the confidence of the delirious pilot by spraying foam (or something) onto the peak of a uniform cap to simulate the gold braid worn by a senior officer?

Comment: Shaving foam, and yes - "Tony’s old-young face, with its angular nose linked to a determined mouth by sharp lines, was made ten, twenty, any number of years older, by the peaked cap with its rim of ‘scrambled egg’ – gold braid – denoting senior rank. The Flight Lieutenant was completely taken in."

Comment: As a youngster, I found the lieutenant's suffering and slow death from radiation poisoning quite disturbing… And it wasn't until many years later that I realised the ‘scrambled egg’ wasn't meant literally :-)